# Registros orfãos , verificando em outra tabela

Tags: sql-server

Tenho uma tabela de fotos:

```
 tbl_fotos
    int_ID  (Pk, int)
    int_IDProduto (int)
    str_foto (varchar(40))
```

e uma tabela para produtos

```
  tbl_produtos
    int_ID (PK, int)
```

**Quero saber quantas fotos existem sem produtos. (fotos orfãs) provavelmente o produto foi apagado e a foto não.**

```
select  int_IDProduto  from tbl_fotos
where  int_IDProduto not in (Select int_IDfrom tbl_produtos)
```

esta certo? me parece trazer mais resultados do que imaginava.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está certo sim. Não precisa do `distinct`, não há motivo algum para duplicar resultado (a não ser que exista a possibilidade de terem fotos iguais nessa tabela com ids diferentes, que é o problema de ter uma PK não natural). Se quer saber apenas quantos, use count:

```
select count(1) from tbl_fotos
where  int_IDProduto not in (Select int_ID from tbl_produtos);
```

Se toda foto deve ser vinculada a um produto válido ou a nenhum, você deveria provavelmente ter a constraint de FK aí:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_fotos ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_fotos_produtos] FOREIGN KEY(int_IDProduto)
REFERENCES tbl_produtos (int_ID);
```

Aí, nesse caso, achar quantas fotos sem produtos seria apenas

```
select count(1) from tbl_fotos where  int_IDProduto is null;
```

Se a ideia, por acaso, é que não existam fotos que não estão vinculadas a produtos, além de criar a constraint acima você deveria passar a coluna para não aceitar null:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_fotos ALTER COLUMN int_IDProduto INT NOT NULL;
```

Em qualquer caso, para saber os IDs das fotos basta substituir `count(1)` por `int_ID`.

Answer (score 1):

Deve ser porque repete os registros.

Para saber quais Ids de produtos não existem mais, use:

```
select distinct int_IDProduto  
from tbl_fotos
where int_IDProduto not in (Select int_ID from tbl_produtos)
```

Para saber quais fotos possuem produtos órfãos, use:

```
select distinct int_ID, str_foto
from tbl_fotos
where int_IDProduto not in (Select int_ID from tbl_produtos)
```

Para saber a quantidade de fotos órfãs, e apenas a quantidade, use:

```
select count(*)
from tbl_fotos
where int_IDProduto not in (Select int_ID from tbl_produtos)
```

Comment: Votei contra porque essa query produz resultado diferente do que ele pediu. Aí você está trazendo os ids de produtos inválidos na tabela de fotos (e, junto, a quantidade de PRODUTOS). Isso é bem diferente do que trazer a quantidade de FOTOS que foi pedida.

Comment: Nada a ver. Onde que ele perguntou de quantidade?

Comment: @PedroLorentz Apesar do OP ter perguntado *"**quantas** fotos existem sem produtos"*, fica evidente que ele quer saber quais para tomar uma ação, tal como removê-las.

Comment: @utluiz e Cigano, o erro persiste porque o distinct está sendo feito sobre o id do produto. Isso não vai dar nem quantas fotos e nem quais são elas.

Comment: @PedroLorentz Minha intenção é apenas de esclarecer as coisas. Do jeito que está a query retorna quais produtos não existem mais. E, Cigano, com a última edição ficou uma resposta bem completa. Assim que eu puder novamente votar irei positivar ambas as respostas.

Comment: Editei a resposta, já que a query anterior produz resultados diferentes do que ele pediu.

Comment: @utluiz, inclui a última linha da minha resposta agora para que ela passe a falar de poder trocar count(1) por int_ID para trazer os ids das fotos. Realmente não tinha colocado isso antes porque era uma mudança simples que assumi que o OP ia conseguir fazer se ele quisesse os IDs. Obrigado pela conselho de melhoria.

Comment: Cigano, o distint continua sendo desnecessário no segundo select, repare que int_ID é PK da tabela. A resposta à pergunta final ainda está errada aqui: "esta certo? me parece trazer mais resultados do que imaginava." e você respondeu com "Deve ser porque repete os registros.", o que não é verdade, a quantidade de registros retornadas está certa.